# Manifolds with isometry group $ SU_n $

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The sphere $ S^n $ equipped with a metric of constant positive curvature $ g $ has orientation preserving isometry group
$$
Iso^+(S^n,g) \cong SO_{n+1}(\mathbb{R})
$$

Indeed every compact group is the isometry group of some manifold see

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87070/can-every-lie-group-be-realized-as-the-full-isometry-group-of-a-riemannian-manif?rq=1

However it is not clear to me how this works in particular examples.

**Is there a "well-known" family of Riemannian manifolds $ M^n $ whose group of orientation preserving isometries is $ SU_n $?**

I know that $ \mathbb{C}P^{n-1} $ with the Fubini Study metric has orientation preserving isometry group $ PU_n $, when $ n $ is even, (see [What is the compact Riemannian manifold $M$ such that $SU(n)/\mathbb{Z}_n$ is the isometry group of $M$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4166101/what-is-the-compact-riemannian-manifold-m-such-that-sun-mathbbz-n-is-th?rq=1)) so that's close but not quite it.